# int[] total not printing

Tags: java, arrays

I'm sorry if this title isn't descriptive; it's hard to explain the problem without the code. My problem is this: I'm running this code

```
 private static Integer[] buffer = new Integer[60];
 private static int sum;
 ...
 public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException{
   ...
   while (true) {
     try {
       main.repaint(); //call paint() method for graphics
       rebuffer();
       getBufferSum();
       //System.out.println(sum);
     } catch (NullPointerException e) {}
     Thread.sleep(1000);
     //}catch(NullPointerException e){e.printStackTrace();}
    }
 }

    private static void getBufferSum() {
        System.out.println("Started");
        int total = 0;
        for(int i = 0; i < 60; i++){
            total += buffer[i];
        }
        System.out.println(total);
        sum = total;
    }

    private static void rebuffer() {
        for(int i = 1; i < 60; i++){
            buffer[i - 1] = buffer[i]; 
        }
        buffer[59] = count;
        //System.out.println(count);
        count = 0;
        System.out.println("Done");
    }
```

And I'm getting this output:

```
Done
Started
Done
Started
Done
Started
...
```

Why is the line `System.out.println(total);` failing to execute?

Comment: I'm not sure that we can guess why your code isn't working based on the snippet you've posted. For better help, consider creating and posting a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example Program](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Also, the first step in solving your problem will be to isolate your problem, meaning it's time to do some serious debugging, either with a debugger that will allow you to step through your code and analyze variables as the program progresses, or with a logger, or with a "poor man's debugger" -- a lot of println statements that expose variable state as the program progresses.

Comment: OMG, does your code really have `catch (NullPointerException e) {}`?? Sorry, but I just saw that and code should never have that sort of thing, ever. You never catch a NPE, and you never ignore an exception. That is seriously the worst kind of code period as it is very dangerous code and is equivalent to trying to drive a car with your eye closed. Just promise never to do this again, please.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels "[...]trying to drive a car with your eye closed" --> if you close your eyes, you might `Thread.sleep(1000l);`. That code makes sense now.

Answer (score 3):

Your `buffer` variable is an array of `Integer`, which is nullable (contrary to primitive `int`, which defaults to `0`).

It's likely that any element has not been initialized before invoking them by index in your `getBufferSum` method, hence a `NullPointerException` that is not logged, hence a sleeping time of 1 second, hence the `"Done"` statement prints thereafter.

You should probably add `e.printStackTrace();` in your `catch` statement to figure this out, instead of sleeping for 1 second.

Also consider debugging your code.

As [Hovercraft Full Of Eels](https://stackoverflow.com/users/522444/hovercraft-full-of-eels) points out, it is considered very bad practice to `catch NullPointerException`s (as most `RuntimeException`s and all `Error`s).

On the long run you should get rid of that `try` / `catch`.